# Cannot send files to SFTP server

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, sftp, winscp

I am trying to automate the sending of files to a SFTP server using a VBA macro in Excel. I wrote this piece of code :

```
Sub SFTPUpload()
Dim winscpExePath As String
    Dim sftpHost As String
    Dim sftpUser As String
    Dim sftpPass As String
    Dim hostKey As String
    Dim sftpKeyPath As String
    Dim sftpRemotePath As String
    Dim sftpLocalPath As String
   
    winscpExePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com"
    sftpHost = "eu-sftp.apps.airliquide.com"
    'sftpHost = "10.152.50.112"
    sftpUser = "al-ald-prod"
    sftpPass = "ssh-rsa 2048 91:cd:88:de:53:93:f7:6d:2f:47:c2:8f:e9:a1:e5:ce"
    sftpKeyPath = "C:\Users\brice.tikiabane\Desktop\SFTP keys - Copie\al-ald-prod-2023-03-01-private_key.ppk"
    sftpRemotePath = "/al-gio-sftp-giocentralbatchprod-s-8ab50e07929c4a698/al-ald-prod/"
    sftpLocalPath = "C:\Users\brice.tikiabane\Documents\ALDE file.txt"
    
    Shell winscpExePath & " /command " & _
        """open sftp://" & sftpUser & "@" & sftpHost & " -privatekey=""" & sftpKeyPath & """ -hostkey=""" & hostKey & """" & _
        " """ & sftpRemotePath & """ " & _
        "put """ & sftpLocalPath & """ " & _
        "exit"""
        MsgBox "Sending successful"


End Sub
```

Even though I successfully reach the "Sending successful", when I check the destination SFTP server's content on WinSCP, I do not see the file I have been trying to send anywhere.

Do you have any suggestions ? I double-checked both the source and remote paths. Is there another function I could use for the sending ?

Thank you for your help and support

I tried sending a file to the SFTP server. Upon running the function, "Sending successful" is displayed, meaning I've reached the end of the function with no issue, yet no file has been left in the destination server when I check its content using WinSCP

Comment: 1) You are missing `cd` command in `" """ & sftpRemotePath & """ " & _` 2) You never set the `hostKey`, while you set `sftpPass` to a value that looks like a *hostkey* and you never use it afterwards.  => change `sftpPass` to `hostKey`. + If it still does not work after you fix these, post a log file. + Show us a screenshot that show how you check that the uploaded file is not there.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl thank you for your support. It indeed worked better upon adding cd and modifying the hostKey.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are missing `cd` command in:  :

   ```
           " """ & sftpRemotePath & """ " & _
   ```

   Should be:

   ```
           "cd """ & sftpRemotePath & """ " & _
   ```
2. You never set the `hostKey`, while you set `sftpPass` to a value that looks like a hostkey and you never use it afterwards. Change `sftpPass` to `hostKey`.

   ```
   hostKey = "ssh-rsa 2048 91:cd:88:de:53:93:f7:6d:2f:47:c2:8f:e9:a1:e5:ce"
   ```